# Splitting one Pdf file to multiple according to the file-size

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have been trying to split one big PDF file to multiple pdf files based on its size. I was able to split it but it only creates one single file and rest of the file data is lost. Means it does not create more than one files to split it. Can anyone please help? Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        PdfReader Split_PDF_By_Size = new PdfReader("C:\\Temp_Workspace\\TestZip\\input1.pdf");
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Temp_Workspace\\TestZip\\File1.pdf"));
        document.open();

        int number_of_pages = Split_PDF_By_Size.getNumberOfPages();
        int pagenumber = 1; /* To generate file name dynamically */
        // int Find_PDF_Size; /* To get PDF size in bytes */
        float combinedsize = 0; /* To convert this to Kilobytes and estimate new PDF size */
        for (int i = 1; i < number_of_pages; i++ ) {
            float Find_PDF_Size;
            if (combinedsize == 0 && i != 1) {
                document = new Document();
                pagenumber++;
                String FileName = "File" + pagenumber + ".pdf";
                copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(FileName));
                document.open();
            }

            copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(Split_PDF_By_Size, i));
            Find_PDF_Size = copy.getCurrentDocumentSize();
            combinedsize = (float)Find_PDF_Size / 1024;
            if (combinedsize > 496 || i == number_of_pages) {
                document.close();
                combinedsize = 0;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("PDF Split By Size Completed. Number of Documents Created:" + pagenumber);                        
    }
    catch (Exception i)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(BTW, it would have been great if you had tagged your question with *itext*, too.)

`PdfCopy` used to close the `PdfReaders` it imported pages from whenever the source `PdfReader` for page imports switched or the `PdfCopy` was closed. This was due to the original intended use case to create **one** target PDF from **multiple** source PDFs in combination with the fact that many users forget to close their `PdfReaders`.

Thus, after you close the first target `PdfCopy`, the `PdfReader` is closed, too, and no further pages are extracted.

If I interpret the most recent checkins into the iText SVN repository correctly, this implicit closing of `PdfReaders` is in the process of being removed from the code. Therefore, with one of the next *iText* versions, your code may work as intended.